# How is this "object expected" JavaScript error possible?

Tags: javascript

Apparently this line of code is triggering "Object expected":

```
var bPid = (b != null && typeof (b.processId) == "number") ? b.processId : 0;
```

Unfortunately I can't step through the code in the debugger since this is an intermittent error that shows up in a Windows SideShow gadget that I'm writing. But, I'd imagine someone should be able to tell me how it's even possible to get object expected given all the checks that I'm doing to attempt to prevent something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `b.processId` without making sure that `b` is an object.

Comment: Shouldn't `typeof(b.processId) == "number"` prevent me from calling `b.processId` in the case of, say, `b = 3`?

Comment: Asking for the `typeof(b.processId)` makes JavaScript evaluate `b.processId`. In case of `b` being the number 3, this would result in `"undefined"`. In case of `b` being `undefined` itself, it would result in an error.

Comment: I was under the impression that the whole point of `typeof` was to let you test if some property existed without actually dereferencing it. But, Firebug agrees that typeof(undefined.processId) gives an error, so I guess not >_<.

Comment: Wait, you're working with a JScript engine? Then my bet is that it's one of JScript quirks. |var b=3; var c=b.processId;| is not an error. b===undefined wouldn't pass the null-check as you correctly said.

Answer (score 4):

It seems `b` is not an object, so I'd `alert(b)` before that line to see if it's been assigned a value at all.

Even if it has a value assigned, it may not be an object, so you might as well ask for `typeof(b) == 'object'`.

Comment: But shouldn't the `b != null` catch that? (Note that I'm not using strict equality `===`.)

Comment: Nope, because if b == 3, that's != null as well. Same with b being an array. You should make sure it's an *object*, not just != null...

Comment: alert(undefined == null); // true

Comment: If `b` is undefined, it short-circuits at `b != null`, since `undefined == null` (even though `undefined !== null`).

Comment: Just as a side note: `typeof` is an operator and not a function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator

Answer (score 2):

Your variable *b* probably doesn’t exist. Try this:

```
var bPid = (typeof b != "undefined" && typeof b.processId == "number") ? b.processId : 0;
```

Comment: Would a (sloppy) `var bPid = (b && typeof b.processId == "number") ? b.processId : 0;` do? After all, both `null` and `undefined` evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @Tomalak: No, you would get a *ReferenceError* if *b* does not exist.

Comment: I meant if `b` was a declared variable with an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 2):

The safest (and the shortest) way to check if the b variable is 'truthy' (in Douglas Crockford's terms) would be

```
var bPid = (b && typeof (b.processId) == "number") ? b.processId : 0;
```

unless you explicitly want to compare it to null (in which case you should compare with === that doesn't do type coersion).

And to be 'truthy' a varible is anything except false, null, undefined, NaN, the number zero, or an empty string.